# Zoom in 4CH mode and Firmware update 1.72

Tags: zoom, zoom-h4n, upgrade, input

I have updated the firmware [on the Zoom H4n]. Now I should be able to control sensitivity on input 1 and 2 separately. And it has worked before but not anymore. I am only able to control sensitivity for 1 and 2 together. Can someone help me with this?

Thx already.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that MENU -> IINPUT -> 1/2 LINK is set to "OFF"